# Inclusion functor is final?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory, limits-colimits, adjoint-functors

For $n\geq 1$ let $K_n$ be the partially ordered set of compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ordered by inclusion. Let $B_n$ be the totally ordered set of closed balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ centered at the origin with radius a positive integer (ordered by inclusion). Consider $K_n$ as a thin category $\underline{K_n}$ and $B_n$ as a thin category $\underline{B_n}$. Is the inclusion functor $I\colon \underline{B_n}\rightarrow \underline{K_n}$ a [final functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/final+functor)? Is there a (high level) abstract-nonsense argument for this?

If $I$ was a right adjoint, this would follow directly (see example 5.2 in the nLab article). I think $I$ is a right adjoint, but do not know what the left adjoint is explicitly. $I$ preserves limits (set union is the limit in both categories). $B_n$ is locally small and for $S\in \underline{K_n}$ the set $\{B_r(0)\}_{r>s}$ (where $s=\operatorname{max}_{x\in S}\vert \vert x \vert \vert$) with the inclusion of $S \subseteq B_r(0)$ is a solution set. By the general adjoint functor theorem $I$ has a left adjoint — namely?

Comment: Given posets $X\subseteq Y$, the inclusion functor $F\colon \underline{X}\rightarrow \underline{Y}$ is final if for every $y\in Y$ there exists $x\in X$ with $y\leq x$. To see this, let $G\colon \underline{Y}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ be any functor whose colimit $\operatorname{colim}(G)$ exists. For any $y\in Y\setminus X$ and pick $x\in X$ with $y\leq x$. Composing $G(y\leq x)$ with the leg $GF(x)\rightarrow \operatorname{colim}(GF)$ makes $\operatorname{colim}(GF)$ a cocone of $G$…

Comment: … By the universal property of the colimit, there thus exists $\operatorname{colim}(G)\rightarrow\operatorname{colim}(GF)$ and $\operatorname{colim}(G)$  is a universal cocone of $GF$. Hence $\operatorname{colim}(G)\cong\operatorname{colim}(GF)$.

Comment: Since any compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded, in your example we of course have that for all $C\in K_n$ there exists an $r\in \mathbb{N}$ with $C\subseteq B_r(0)$. Thus $I$ is final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$I$ is a right adjoint; its left adjoint sends a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to the smallest ball with integer radius containing it. Compare to the example of the inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$ which is both a left and a right adjoint, with its left adjoint given by ceiling and its right adjoint given by floor.

Comment: +1: This ties in nicely with my last comment. To prove finality of $I$ we only need that any compact set is contained in a closed ball with integer radius. The left adjoint of $I$ picks out the universal/smallest such object.

Comment: It wasn't the question, I know, but analogously to the inclusion $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the functor $I$ is also a left adjoint. Its right adjoint sends a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to the greatest ball with integer radius contained in it.